# HELP, how can i make this

Tags: mathematics

You can use whatever you want but must be equal on every item.

12_4_5=0

1_4_5=1

2_4_5=2

3_4_5=3

4_4_5=4

Comment: Is there any particular set of operations that is allowed? Allowing anything to be used can lead to brute force solving with square roots, factorials, and rounding. Is each _ supposed to be replaced with exactly one symbol or can they be replaced with multiple or none? Also, do you have a source for the puzzle? Puzzles from others are okay in most cases, but require attribution to the creator.

Answer (score 4):

I'll take a guess and say that:

> 12 monkeys 4 dolphins 5 kangaroos = 0 cows, 1 boat 4 hooks 5 humans = 1 human killer shark

I can't figure out the rest.

> I'm saying this is really unclear as to what you want us to do.  Is this homework? Is this a competition thing? what can we use?